# how to add "donate" button with PayPal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, payment, paypal

I want to add some kind of `donate with paypal`

to my website.

How can I implemet this?

I add a `paypal` button and then

I need to call some paypal API method with my paypal email, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the Html button using the "Create a Button" wizard (will output an html form with the paypal parameters) without the need of calling Paypal's API or Paypal IPN.

https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_donate-intro-outside

Use Paypal API or IPN only if you want to track the incoming payment. For example: Give an extra service to a user that paid you.

Comment: If i want to track the donations - I need to use the API. Which method?

Comment: Have a look at the PayPal donation widget, which can automatically track the progress: https://giving.paypallabs.com/authenticate/review